# how this php codes option(textarea field) will inserted to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

hi guys you have some idea about this codes. textarea submitted to database. because i have a connection.php but it is not inserting to database pls help me using option textarea. can you help me also for the phpmyadmin SQL what name, type, etc should i put tnx

```
select.html

     <html lang="en">
     <title>NTF Catering Service</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">              </script> 
       <script src="js/js.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
       <form action="create.php" method="post">

         <select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
         <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
         <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
         <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
         <option value="item4">Item 4</option>
          <option value="item5">Item 5</option>
        </select>


    <button id="copy">Copy</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

     <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove">


<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
    </select>
     </html>

connection.php

     <?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "copy";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);
      ?>

submit.php
   <?php
include 'connection.php';

$food1 = $_POST['food1'];
$food2 = $_POST['food2'];
$food3 = $_POST['food3'];
$food4 = $_POST['food4'];
$food5 = $_POST['food5'];


if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "please fill out the form";
    header('Location: select.html');
 } else {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO remove(food1, food2, food3, food4, food5) VALUES ('".$food1."', '".$food2."', '".$food3."','".$food4."','".$food5."');";
         mysql_query($link, $sql);
    echo "User has been added!";
    header('Location: select.html');

     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are posting the form data to the wrong file? Should be posting to submit.php, not create.php

Comment: `<form action="create.php" method="post">` vs `submit.php` ;-) Also, sanitise your `POST` values! Reguarding `mysql_connect` - read http://uk1.php.net/function.mysql-connect

Comment: You have not escaped your input strings, so your query will fail if any of the input contains quote marks or other SQL reserved characters. Easy to break. Plus that makes it vulnerable to being hacked. Also, **please do not use the `mysql_xxx()` functions -- they are obsolete and deprecated.** You should use the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: @daniel mensing yah change it already sry;) but still not inserting to database

Comment: @Spudley ok tnx for that:)

Answer (score -1):

Let your `INSERT INTO` statement be of this form:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO remove(food1, food2, food3, food4, food5) VALUES ($food1, $food2, $food3, $food4, $food5)";
```

Comment: Change mysql_query($link, $sql); <br>
to mysql_query($link, $sql) or die(mysql_error());<br>
to see possible sql errors you have

Answer (score -1):

Your action is wrong and should be `submit.php`

Also please don't use `mysql_*` functions, because they're deprecated.

Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Also use `prepared statements`, to prevent SQL Injections.

Example for your **connection.php**:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "copy";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
?>
```

Example for your **submit.php** (with prepared statement):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$food1 = $_POST['food1'];
$food2 = $_POST['food2'];
$food3 = $_POST['food3'];
$food4 = $_POST['food4'];
$food5 = $_POST['food5'];


if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "please fill out the form";
    header('Location: select.html');
 } else {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO remove(food1, food2, food3, food4, food5) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
         $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss",$food1,$food2,$food3,$food4,$food5);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         echo "User has been added!";
         header('Location: select.html');

     }
?>
```

Comment: in phpmyadmin SQL ill used name=food type=text ??

Comment: Depends on your functionality. But yes, TEXT is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, then you can use TEXT. If you have very very long text, you could also use LONGTEXT, but I'm sure TEXT is ok.

Comment: Can you just take a look at your food-variables? echo all $food variables and look, what the output is

Comment: i have this code for the html,
<form action="submit.php" method="post">

<select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
    <option value="foodA">foodA</option>
    <option value="foodB">foodB</option>
    <option value="foodC">foodC</option>
    <option value="foodD">foodD</option>
    <option value="foodE">foodE</option>
</select>


<button type="button" id="copy" onclick="yourFunction()">Copy</button>
<button type="button" id="remove" onclick="yourFunction()">Remove</button>

<select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove">
 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />

Comment: So this cannot work. Your select got no name and then, you've got an array of values.

Comment: so what should i do? to run it?

Comment: Well..give your select a name like "foods" and then you can get the selected values with foreach ($_POST ['foods'] as $onefood) { ...}